# How to execute a virtual function from a base class without the explicit call of Base::func() in a derived class?

Tags: c++

I'm a newbie in C++ and have a question. I can't find any related stuff for this question on Google.

Is it possible in C++ for code in a virtual function to be called from the base class without invoking it with `Base::func()` in the derived class?

Here is an example of what I mean:

```
class Base {  
public:  
    virtual void func(void) { cout << "Base func()" << endl; }  
};

class Derived : Base {  
public:  
    virtual void func(void) { cout << "Derived func()" << endl; }  
};
```

The output should be the following when the function `func` is called from `Derived`:

```
Base func()  
Derived func()
```

Is this even possible in C++?  Or, is there another way to implement this behavior?

Comment: Totally unrelated to the question but C++ has an `override` identifier that will cause a compile error if the function isn't actually overriding anything, it's very handy for catching things like a missing `virtual` specifier or slightly misspelled function `virtual void func(void) override { cout << "Derived func()" << endl; }`. It's also a nice way of pointing out to a programmer that the function is being overridden.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Good to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the base class get the calls first by making the interface non-virtual, and then call the (private) derived function from there:

```
class Base {  
public:  
    void func()
    {
        cout << "Base func()" << endl;

        derived_func();
    }

private:
    virtual void derived_func() { }

};

class Derived : Base {  
private:  
    virtual void derived_func() { cout << "Derived func()" << endl; }  
};
```

Comment: Great! That was it, what I wanted to know! Many thanks!

Answer (score 4):

> Is that intention even possible in C++? Or is there a other way to implement this behavior in C++?

You can get that behavior **only if** you add

```
Base::func();
```

in the implementation of `Derived::func()`. The language does not provide a mechanism to make that automatic.

Answer (score 0):

You have call the base class in derived class implementation to make that happen

```
class Base {  
public:  
    virtual void func(void) { cout << "Base func()" << endl; }  
};

class Derived : Base {  
public:  
    virtual void func(void) 
    { 
        Base::function();
        cout << "Derived func()" << endl; 
    }  
};
```

But this is still calling `Base::func()` from `Derived::func()`

You can, however, achieve what you want *if* the `func()` was actually your constructor.